# Quickbooks - Select all payments for an invoice

Tags: php, quickbooks, quickbooks-online

I am trying to query for all payments assigned to an invoice using the consolibyte quickbooks php toolkit. I was hoping I could pull these back using a query but so far the only way I can see to do it is by grabbing all payments and then looping through and checking what is within the LinkedTxn array and checking if it has a type of 'Invoice' and that the 'TxnId' value matches my stored invoice id. What I have so far is this which gets the payments but is obviously not an option going forward as there may be tens of thousands of payments in the system:

```
public function getAllPaymentsForInvoice(Invoice $invoice)
{
    $query = "SELECT * FROM Payment";

    $payments = $this->qbPaymentService->query($this->context, $this->realm, $query);

    $lines = [];

    foreach ($payments as $payment) {
        $num_lines = $payment->countLine();
        for ($i = 0; $i < $num_lines; $i++) {
            $line = $payment->getLine($i);

            $txnId = $this->parseResponse($line->getLinkedTxn()->getTxnId());// convert {-1} to 1
            $txnType = $line->getLinkedTxn()->getTxnType();

            if ($txnType == 'Invoice' && $txnId == $invoice->qb_ref) {
                $lines[] = $line;
            }
        }
    }

    return $lines;
}
```

Can anyone push me in the direction of a better way?

Answer (score 0):

There's no easy, one-liner way to do this using the QuickBooks Online API. This just isn't something that QuickBooks Online itself supports.

There are two separate approaches you could take to optimize what you're doing.

1. The payments applied should always be for the same customer as the invoices, so you can change your query to `SELECT * FROM Payment WHERE CustomerRef = 'xyz'` where `xyz` is the `CustomerRef` from the invoice. Then, use your existing code to check exactly which invoices payments are applied to.
2. Use the CDC functionality to keep a cached copy of all payments in your own database, and query your own database for the information instead (a normal SQL database is considerably more flexible and query-able than what QuickBooks Online offers).

The CDC functionality is specifically designed to allow you to keep an accurate, cached copy of the QuickBooks data in your own application, specifically to address situations like you're running into. You pass it a timestamp, and it gives you everything that has changed since that timestamp. By remembering the date/time you last ran the `->cdc(...)` method, you can continually get lightweight updates to any objects that have changed since you last queried them.

```
<?php
$CDCService = new QuickBooks_IPP_Service_ChangeDataCapture();

// What types of objects do you want to get? 
$objects = array( 
    'Payment', 
    'Invoice', 
    );

// The date they should have been updated after 
$timestamp = QuickBooks_Utilities::datetime($datetime_you_last_called_cdc_method);
$cdc = $CDCService->cdc($Context, $realm, 
    $objects,
    $timestamp);

// You would cache all the stuff you get back here
print_r($cdc);
```

Docs links:

- https://github.com/consolibyte/quickbooks-php/blob/master/docs/partner_platform/example_app_ipp_v3/example_cdc.php
- https://developer.intuit.com/docs/0100_accounting/0300_developer_guides/change_data_capture

Comment: Hi Keith. Only just noticed you had posted an answer. I have so far gone with a solution involving getting the linked transactions from the invoice, imploding them and then doing a query on the Payment table for payments where the ids are in the string. e.g: "SELECT * FROM Payment WHERE Id IN ('" . implode("','", $paymentIds) . "')". Where $paymentIds has been pre-processed to get all linked transactions from the invoice. This seems to be doing what I need. Does this seem like a good solution to you?

Comment: this solution with "IN (..)" works perfectly fine and, IMO, should be an accepted answer

Answer (score 0):

The question is quite old, anyway, in case someone else is looking for answer:

```
$InvoiceService = new QuickBooks_IPP_Service_Invoice();

// $invoices = $InvoiceService->query($Context, $realm, "SELECT * FROM Invoice STARTPOSITION 1 MAXRESULTS 10");

// If, we have QB Invoice # i.e.DocNumber

$invoice_no = 1001;

$invoices = $InvoiceService->query($Context, $realm, "SELECT * FROM Invoice WHERE DocNumber = '$invoice_no' ");

    foreach ($invoices as $Invoice)
    {
        $txnId = 0;
        if (is_object($Invoice->getLinkedTxn()) && $Invoice->getLinkedTxn()->getTxnType() == 'Payment') {

            $txnId = $Invoice->getLinkedTxn()->getTxnId();          
        }
                
        print('Invoice # '.$Invoice->getDocNumber().' has a total of $'.$Invoice->getTotalAmt().' and Linked Payment ID: ' . $txnId . "\n");
     }
```